# How to attach mouse over event in the given code?

Tags: events, jquery, mouseover, attachment, mouseclick-event

I am trying to use http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/06/beautiful-portfolio-html5-jquery/ which is having a tutorial page @ http://tutorialzine.com/2011/06/beautiful-portfolio-html5-jquery/

I want to add mouse over event or click event, but my code is not working.

```
$("ul#stage li").click(function() {
    alert("Over")

});
```

I added the event in document ready function, but not working. Please help. I tried similar code for 'hover' event.

Comment: Not enough information in the code provided. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be nice, such as http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com.

Comment: @ManseUK &Matt Ball : Instead of pasting whole HTML I added the plugin that am using

Comment: @Sam Rudolph - the problem is that its working fine in the example code ... where as yours doesnt .. your code is different from the example .. thats why its not working !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("ul#stage li").live('click', function() {
    alert("Over")

});
```

---

or for both events

```
$("ul#stage li").live({
  click: function() {
    // do something on click
  },
  mouseover: function() {
    // do something on mouseover
  }
});
```